# Convert jQuery ready function to TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm trying to replace some old code that uses jQuery, to the new way without it.

The old code, using the ready function:

```js
function myFunc() { }

$(function() {
  myFunc();
});
```

I found this equivalent at ["You Might Not Need jQuery"](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready):

```js
function myFunc() { }

function ready(fn) {
  if (document.readyState != 'loading')
    fn();
  else
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
}
ready(myFunc);
```

I'm using TypeScript, so it complains about `fn` being implicit `any`. I'd like to avoid that.

I tried: `fn: Function`, but the compiler complains about the overloads to `addEventListener`, and I'm unsure how to handle it.

How do I avoid `any`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFunc() { }

function ready(fn:() => void) {
  if (document.readyState != 'loading')
    fn();
  else
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
}
ready(myFunc);
```

You can type it like this.

Comment: yeh, usually when your function does not return anything we do void.
If your fn function returns a number or a string you change void accordingly

Comment: If your fn function can be different you can use something like function overloading :

https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/function-overloading/#:~:text=In%20TypeScript%2C%20function%20overloading%2C%20or,parameters%20or%20different%20parameter%20types.